# throw error with inner error on typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to throw an Error with inner Error, but Error constructor doesn't have a inner error parameter.

For example, in c# I do the following:

```
try 
{
  var a = 3;
  var b = 0;
  var c = a/b;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  throw new Exception("Your custom message", ex);
}
```

How can I do something similar to this with typescript? Maybe an NPM package? I was looking for it but I don't found any package for this

Comment: You can define [custom error type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Custom_Error_Types) with `innerError` property and appropriate constructor.

Comment: If you take out the `Exception` before `ex` your code will work in JS.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Error class doesn't define a constructor with two or more parameters.

Comment: You can concatenate the messages. Or using a prototype or “class” you can extend from the standard error to make your own.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, I will build my own Error class. Also, I'm thinking on release as npm package under MIT license, for anyone that need this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your custom error class. It would be something similar to:

```
export class CustomError extends Error {
    public innerError: Error | undefined;
    // any other variable definition if needed

    public constructor(message?: string, innerError?: Error) {
        super(message);
        this.innerError = innerError;
        // any other logic or variable assignment if needed
    }
}
```

And then in your code:

```
try 
{
  const a = 3;
  const b = 0;
  const c = a/b;
} catch(ex) {
  throw new CustomError("Your custom message", ex as Error);
}
```